# RavenDB Uninstall SSL causes 503 on custom port

Tags: ssl, ravendb

I was playing around on my local machine with getting RavenDb to use SSL running in server mode. It worked, after a while.

I am now trying to role back to before SSL, and am having a weird issue. Under http, I was using port number 123 (for example). I changed this to use port 443 (in order to use https).

After uninstalling the SSL cert and rolling back the `Raven.Server.exe.config` file (so `Raven/Port` is now set to 123 again), and load the studio, I get a 503 Service Unavailable error. The weird bit is, if I now change the port number to 122 (or anything *not* 123), the studio loads fine under http. It's as if that port number has been destroyed or something.

My question is this: What the flip is going on and how can I fix it?

By the way, I can't just change the port number, that would involve getting my whole team to change it on their dev environments.

An example of my `Raven.Server.exe.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
        <add key="Raven/Port" value="123"/>
        <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Database\System"/>
        <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
        <add key="Raven/HostName" value="ravendb.mydomain.com" />
    </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Analyzers;Plugins"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
Raven.Server.exe --uninstallSSL
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something simple. Just to be clear, this is different to the `Raven.Server.exe /uninstallSSL=C:\mycert.pfx=mypassword` that I've been trying?

Comment: Yes, it is off the top of my head, but that is what it looks like, I think it is ==, not =, though.

Comment: Doh, typo in my comment. I'll give it a try later and see what happens. Thanks, Ayende.

Comment: this isn't working, even updating to the latest build will not let me use the custom port number. I've had to get my team to change the port number in their server config files. It's as if the port number has been made unusable.